# Cell value obtained with Apache POI from Excel Spreadsheet prints same value as Java String but IF statement does not say they are the same?

Tags: java, string, comparison, cell

I am reading cells from an Excel spreadsheet. I am reading the first cell in each row, and comparing them to a String object that I have passed into the function. The function correctly iterates over all rows and accesses the first cell in each row, but when comparing them to the String object parameter, the IF statement does not execute, despite both the value obtained from the cell and the String parameter printing the same thing. I have used '==' operators, as well as .equals() but nothing seems to let the IF statement execute.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> returnCurrency(String currency, String fileName) throws IOException
{

FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(newFile(fileName));

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

ArrayList<Double> currencyRateArray = new ArrayList<Double>();

for( int rowNum = 0; rowNum <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++)
{
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    Cell tempCell = row.getCell(0);

System.out.printf("temp cell has value of:%s\n",tempCell.getStringCellValue());

System.out.printf("currency variable is: %s\n", currency);
if(currency.equals(tempCellString))
{
    System.out.println("Found the currency\n");
}
}
}
```

When I pass the parameter String as "USD", both print statements print "USD", but it will never print "Found the currency" as that IF statement does not execute. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - the cell in the database had the value 'USD ' instead of 'USD'.